# AngularJs database data internationalization

Tags: angularjs, database, internationalization

I´m developing a i18n AngularJS application. I would need to display the info in english and also spanish. I´m currently using ng-translate for static content and it´s really good. But I would need to translate some info coming from database, such as the typical dropdown (select field) with country names. Depending on the user language settings, there values in the combo should be displayed in english or spanish.

1. I don´t know what is the best architectural approach. I mean, I think in two first approaches:

   1.1 I have a table in database with the countries in just one default language (english). When I get this list to display these values are dinamically translated somehow.

   1.2 I have a table in db with so many columns as languages with the countries in different languages. When I get the list I use the language settings to get the right column.

I don´t know if there is any other approach. I like 1.1. But, I´m not sure if I can implement it and how. I also would need to display these values ordered.

**UPDATE**

To enrich the final solution. You can have a look at next post, related to how to design a multilingual database (design pattern).
 http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/translation-multilingualmultilanguage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tend to go with 1.2, as that way you are in control of the translations.  Country names probably aren't going to be much of an issue, but if there is anything more complicated, like phrases and such, then I would definitely go with 1.2, as current translation software is likely to lose nuances in translation that could be important.  1.2 would probably also make sorting slightly easier.

Comment: Hi BlackICE, I really take into account your answer. Probably, you are right and finally I go go this approach, but before check your answer as the correct one, I would like to listen some more comments.